# Using "force=true" in .npmrc triggers warning message: how to disable it?

Tags: npm, npm-install

In my project we have some dependencies that work well together but their versions have some conflicts, and this forces us to use `--force` whenever we want to run `npm i`.

To avoid confusions and errors between developers, I've created an `.npmrc` file with the `force=true` parameter so it runs with `--force` by default:

```
package-lock=false
force=true
```

However, this does not only affect the `install` script, but also others like `start` and `test`, which makes an annoying warning message to appear over and over again:

[image: using --force Recommended protections disabled]

This message appears in the middle of other printed messages in console, and it appears many times. When executing tests, it also appears in between `console.log` and other traces, making them hard to read as it just replaces the content. This is the trace of a failed test:

[image: failed test with HTML output that gets interrupted by warning]

Is there any way I can disable this warning message (or make it appear just once, as it should be)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this does not solve exactly the problem, it gets rid of it. Add `--loglevel=error` as a parameter or, if you're using an `.npmrc` file, just add:

```
force=true
loglevel=error
```

This will get rid of the `WARN` messages.

However, this does not solve the initial problem, as those `WARN` messages should not interfere with other log traces in the console in the first place, and that they should be squashed to be shown just once and not so many times as they offer no valuable information and just add noise to the traces.